# " 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" while trying to create file in the C:\ drive

Tags: c#, file, filestream

I'm doing this project where I grab some information and save it to a file. While trying to create that file, I always get an `System.UnauthorizedAccesssException` error. I've tried adding a manifest file and requiring admin, still doesn't work. I've also released it and ran the program through the `\bin` folder, and it still didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
public static void CreateFile(string path, string name)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Starting to create file...");
    string Name = name;
    string path2 = path;
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(path2, Name);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("File Created");
    }
}
```

I also tried going to the Microsoft website and using their method of creating a file, and it still didn't work, I got the same error!

Question is, how I give access to the program in order to write to the `C:\` drive?

Comment: do you have permission to the location? Possibly not....

Comment: @MitchWheat What do you mean? With administrator privilege's, I do but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Ipwnusck : do you really have "administrator privilege's" (sic)? Even under UAC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default most user accounts lack the necessary access to write directly to the `C:\` drive.  The exception, `UnauthorizedAccessException`, indicates that this is the case here.

To make this work you're going to need to either

1. Pick a more standard location to write the file
2. Give the account under which this program runs access to the `C:\` drive.

Of the two #1 is by far the more preferable option