# Download a file after unzipping it from azure in c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I have zipped a file and upload to a blob in azure , but I am unable to download it after unzipping it. I have tried the below code but it is throwing error:

```
public FileStream Download(string strPath)
{
    Stream fs = GetFile(strPath);
    using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(fs))
    {
        var entry = zip.Entries.First();
        var memoryStream = entry.Open();
        string filename = "Report_" + GetUploadTime();
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filename,
                                               FileMode.CreateNew,
                                               FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream); // fileStream is not populated
            return fileStream;
        }
    }
}
```

`System.UnauthorizedAccessException` occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code, I do not want to create any folder or keep it anywhere just unzip and download how to do it.

```
public Stream GetFile(string strPath)
{
    try
    {
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(strPath);
        string account = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlobContainer"];
        string key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlobKey"];
        string connectionString =
            string.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}",
                          account, key);
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
        CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("reportportalblob");
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

        Stream blobStream = blob.OpenRead();

        return blobStream;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // download failed
        // handle exception
        throw;
    }
}
```

I have search for some code but I am not getting anything, please help.

Comment: According to your error message, I suppose it is related with the file access permissions.  I find a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928736/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-occurred-in-mscorlib-dll-while-trying-to) which has similar issue. You could refer to. And you could set a break point to check your code lines one by one. Besides, you could also provide the screenshot about running result  for us.

Comment: @JanleyZhang Can you post me a link or something where I can get a code for zip download.

Comment: Did you mean you have unzipped your zip file in azure container, you want to download all files to local folder?

Comment: No i don want to put it any folder i just wont to download the zip file then unzipping it and whatever file it has just return it from the filestramreasult so that it get downloaded

Answer (score 0):

We could get the unzip stream with following code.

```
public MemoryStream GetFile(string strPath)
        {
            try
            {
                var filename = Path.GetFileName(strPath);
                string account = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountName"];
                string key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountKey"];
                string containerName = "test";
                string connectionString =$"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={account};AccountKey={key}";
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
                var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
                MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
                blob.DownloadToStream(memory);
                var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memory, ZipArchiveMode.Read, true);
                var entry = zipArchive.Entries.First();
                if (entry != null)
                {
                    var stream = entry.Open();
                    memory = new MemoryStream();
                    stream.CopyTo(memory);
                    memory.Position = 0;
                    return memory;
                }

                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // download failed
                // handle exception
                throw;
            }
        }
```

If we want to down to file, then we could use  `File.WriteAllBytes(strPath,memory.ToArray());` or  `fileStream.Write(memory.ToArray(),0,memory.ToArray().Length-1);`

```
 public void Download(string strPath)
    {
            var memory = GetFile(strPath);

            string filename = "Report_" + DateTime.Now;
            var fileStream = new FileStream(filename,
            FileMode.CreateNew,
            FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            // File.WriteAllBytes(strPath,memory.ToArray());
            fileStream.Write(memory.ToArray(),0,memory.ToArray().Length-1);
    }
```